# static django css files are not loading up

Tags: html, css, django, static, django-staticfiles

I downloaded a free Template and I am setting it up so that I can design its backend. The template i download can be found here: [Pillow Selling website free template from colorlib.][1]
After going through many Q&A's from different problem who had the same problem as me. I set up the things as follows:

```
My settings file look like this:
other settings...
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static"),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static')
```

---

```
I included this in my app urls.py
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

---

```
my index.html has all the .css, .png, .jpg files linked like this 
<link rel="icon" href="{% static 'staticfiles/img/favicon.png' %}">
```

I have done this before too with some other website but I don't know why is this not working this time.

Comment: why do you have this `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static')` instead of `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')`?

Comment: @Hisham___Pak after doing what you said I am getting this error:
django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
?: (staticfiles.E002) The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting.

System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).

Comment: some files are being linked but some are not and I don't know what are some files that not being linked but the main style.css is not being linked and i am sure about it.

Comment: Remove `STATIC_ROOT`

Comment: Still the same error. I am really upset by now because i was learning backend developement because frontend sucks but from 5 hours i m stuck at this

Answer (score 0):

So after seeking more i got the answer the problem was with the static linking of the file, I removed

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static')
from settings.py

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
from urls.py
```